# App crashes when using Vibrator, even though hasVibrator() returns true

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

I'm working on a small app that involves vibration, and whenever the `vibrate()` function is called, the app crashes. The stack trace links back to the vibrator.vibrate() line with the text "Vibrator: Failed to vibrate." vibrator. There are also a couple of `DeadObjectExceptions` and `RuntimeExceptions` which all link to Android classes. This only happens on some phones, others it works perfectly.

`hasVibrator()` returns `true`, and the vibrator object is non-null, and the phone has a vibrator, so I can't figure out what's wrong. Perhaps I am trying to vibrate too soon after the vibrator object has been created, or I am creating the vibrator object too soon in the `onCreate()` method?

Here is the part of the code where I am using the `vibrate()` method:

```
//vibrate only if exists
if (vibrating) 
{
    long[] pattern = {0, power, target - power};
    try 
    {
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        vibrating = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the full exception and the code? Thank you.

Comment: @NewtronLabs I don't have access to one of the failing phones right now, but I'll add it tomorrow when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [getSystemService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) you can expect to get the service or null if the class is not a supported system service.

Now, since you said you are getting certain exceptions on different devices you can catch those exceptions.

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

if(vibrator != null)
{
    try
    {
       long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };
       vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    }
    catch(DeadObjectExceptions e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already checking for a blanket Exception (I know this isn't good practice, it was just for testing) but it still crashes.